# Is there any other way to get the count of records in the list<classmodel> in .cshtml?

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

I am new to MVC, Kendo grid and Jquery, Seems tricky to me as I am trying to get the count of model bind to the grid to perform the condition check i.e, to show or hide the div elements and a button.

Having my data bind, div elements inside the fieldset.

When i try to get the count from the grid data source I **could** able to get it, but I want to get the count like @model.count? but I couldn't.
FYI, I **couldn't** get the model value when debugging in console.
The way of binding, i.e from partial view @model List at the top.
Is there any other way to get the count of records in the list?

## Code

```
<fieldset>
   <div class="title" id="msgduplicate">This may be a duplicate Contact. Does this Contact match any of 
        the existing Contacts, below?</div>
   <div class="title" id="msgnoduplicate">No duplicate record found, click Continue to Save the 
        Contact.</div>

     @(Html.SecureGrid<ContactViewModel>()
                                  .Name("DuplicateContactGrid")
                                  .Columns(columns =>
                                  {
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.ContactUid).Hidden(true);
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.ContactRelUid).Hidden(true);
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.ContactEntity).Hidden(true);
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.ResourceUid).Hidden(true);
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.ManagingOrgUid).Hidden(true);
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName).Width(100)
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { title = "FirstName" });
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.LastName).Width(100)
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { title = "LastName" });
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.PhoneNumber).Width(100)
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { title = "PhoneNumber" });
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.FaxNumber).Width(100)
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { title = "FaxNumber" });
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.RoleNames).Width(100)
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { title = "RoleNames " });
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.Notes).Width(150)
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Notes" });
                                  })
                                  .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                                  .Pageable()
                                  .Navigatable()
                                  .Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Endless(true))
                                  .BindTo(Model)
                                   .Events(e => 
                                      e.Change("selectDuplicateContact").DataBound("setPasGridItems"))
                                  .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
                                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Server().Model(model => 
                                   model.Id(gd => gd.ContactUid))))
</fieldset>
```

```
function () {
            debugger;
            var grid = $("#DuplicateContactGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var count = grid.dataSource.total();
            if (count > 0) {
                debugger;
                $("#submit").hide();
                $("#msgnoduplicate").hide();
                $("#msgduplicate").show();
            } else {
                $("#submit").show();
                $("#msgnoduplicate").show();
                $("#msgduplicate").hide();

            }
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is that you need to access mvc model in javascript code. Below is the reference. In your script section  use below mention code. After this one you can access model property from console and able to get the counts`@section script {
  var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); //For javascript object 
}`

Comment: Thanks for the time, I was trying to take the count and display accordingly a button in UI, which I was processing the count from previous grid.

Answer (score 0):

To just simply have access to the number of items within your model (which is a collection) in javascript, you can use:

```
var count = @Html.Raw(Model.Count());
```

Note that this is determined at the time the view is rendered, so this will not handle changing number of rows properly. If that is a requirement, you should continue getting the count from the grid directly and call your function as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I have handled in another way to take the count. Getting the grid count sometime may be false.